# Invalid JSON response from PHP?

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to parse a `JSON` response from my `PHP` files. The first `AsyncTask` returns valid results, the 2nd does not. I believe the problem is in my "mysql_queries.php".

```
 public class GeneralAssets extends ListFragment {
View view;
EditText cn, pn;
ActionBar ab;

private String url = "http://192.168.x.x/questions.php";
private String companyName, projectName;    

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.general_assets_questions, container,
            false);

    ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
    cn = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.company_input);
    pn = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.project_input);       

    Button load = (Button) view
            .findViewById(R.id.generalAssets_load_button_ID);
    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean large = getResources().getConfiguration()
                .isLayoutSizeAtLeast(Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            new LoadAllQuestions().execute();
        }
    });         

    return view;
}   

class LoadAllQuestions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_QUESTIONS = "questions";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "display_name";
    private static final String TAG_FIELD = "field_type";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;     

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray questions = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading questions. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        // getting JSON string from URL
        companyName = cn.getText().toString();
        projectName = pn.getText().toString();
        String componentName = (String) ab.getSelectedTab().getText();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                3);
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", companyName));
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", projectName));
        nameValuePairs
        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("component", componentName));           

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
                nameValuePairs);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Questions: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found: getting Array of Questions
                questions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONS);

                // looping through All Questions
                for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String field = c.getString(TAG_FIELD);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_FIELD, field);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    questionsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Log.v("ERROR", "No JSON for you!");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //Updating parsed JSON data into ListView                    
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                        questionsList,
                        R.id.genA_layout,
                        new String[] { TAG_FIELD, TAG_NAME },
                        new int[] { R.id.answer, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

The "SearchPosts" class returns the following in the `Log.v` "results" `String` Which is the `JSON` response I'm looking for.

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "display_name": "Store #",
            "field_type": "Text Field",
            "option_value": ""
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Address",
            "field_type": "Text Field",
            "option_value": ""
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Type of Business",
            "field_type": "Drop Down Menu",
            "option_value": "Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther"
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Is this business good?",
            "field_type": "Radio",
            "option_value": "Yes\r\nNo"
        },
        {
            "display_name": "Are they nice people?",
            "field_type": "Check Box",
            "option_value": "Yes\r\nNo"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

The "LoadAllQuestions" class returns this and then crashes

```
06-02 02:24:05.909: E/json data(17350): json result <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined 
index: company in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_queries.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br /><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: project in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_queries.php</b> on
line <b>5</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: component in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_queries.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />No results found
```

Here are my `PHP` files

**questions.php**

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';
require 'mysql_queries.php';

 if ($query_run = mysql_query($questions_query)) {
if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == NULL) {
    echo ('No results found');
} else {            
    $response ['questions'] = array();      
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $info = array();
        $info['display_name'] = $row['display_name'];
        $info ['field_type'] = $row['field_type'];
        $info ['option_value'] = $row['option_value'];          

        array_push($response["questions"], $info);          
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1; 
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
$response["success"] = 0; 
$response["message"] = "No data found"; 
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

**mysql_queries**

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$company_name = $_POST['company'];
$project_name = $_POST['project'];
$component_name = $_POST['component'];

$questions_query = "SELECT CFM.display_name, CFM.field_type, CFM.option_value
                FROM company_mast
                LEFT JOIN component_mast 
                ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
                LEFT JOIN CustomField_mast CFM 
                ON CFM.Company_ID = Component_mast.Company_ID
                AND CFM.Component_ID = component_Mast.Component_ID
                WHERE component_mast.component_name =  '".$component_name."'
                AND (component_mast.project_id = '".$project_name."'
                OR company_mast.company_name =  '".$company_name."')";                  
 ?>
```

So why does the first `AsyncTask` return a valid response and the 2nd one come up `null`?

My educated guess is that the `POST` goes out of scope by the time the "LoadAllQuestions" class tries to parse the `JSON` response, but I'm new to this and I don't know how to fix it.

**Edit**
I adjusted the code from suggestions. I am receiving the proper `JSON` response but I am now receiving this in my `logcat`.

```
 06-02 03:16:27.539: E/json data(19020): json result {"questions": [{"display_name":"Store #","field_type":"Text Field","option_value":""},{"display_name":"Address","field_type":"Text Field","option_value":""},{"display_name":"Type of Business","field_type":"Drop Down Menu","option_value":"Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther"},{"display_name":"Is this business good?","field_type":"Radio","option_value":"Yes\r\nNo"},{"display_name":"Are they nice people?","field_type":"Check Box","option_value":"Yes\r\nNo"}],"success":1}
 06-02 03:16:27.539: D/All Questions:(19020): {"success":1,"questions":[{"option_value":"","field_type":"Text Field","display_name":"Store #"},{"option_value":"","field_type":"Text Field","display_name":"Address"},{"option_value":"Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther","field_type":"Drop Down Menu","display_name":"Type of Business"},{"option_value":"Yes\r\nNo","field_type":"Radio","display_name":"Is this business good?"},{"option_value":"Yes\r\nNo","field_type":"Check Box","display_name":"Are they nice people?"}]}

    06-02 03:35:11.069: E/json data(19250): json result {"questions":[{"display_name":"Store #","field_type":"Text Field","option_value":""},{"display_name":"Address","field_type":"Text Field","option_value":""},{"display_name":"Type of Business","field_type":"Drop Down Menu","option_value":"Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther"},{"display_name":"Is this business good?","field_type":"Radio","option_value":"Yes\r\nNo"},{"display_name":"Are they nice people?","field_type":"Check Box","option_value":"Yes\r\nNo"}],"success":1}
06-02 03:35:11.079: D/All Questions:(19250): {"success":1,"questions":[{"option_value":"","field_type":"Text Field","display_name":"Store #"},{"option_value":"","field_type":"Text Field","display_name":"Address"},{"option_value":"Education\r\nHealth\r\nComputers\r\nFood\r\nRetail\r\nOther","field_type":"Drop Down Menu","display_name":"Type of Business"},{"option_value":"Yes\r\nNo","field_type":"Radio","display_name":"Is this business good?"},{"option_value":"Yes\r\nNo","field_type":"Check Box","display_name":"Are they nice people?"}]}
06-02 03:35:11.109: D/AndroidRuntime(19250): Shutting down VM
06-02 03:35:11.109: W/dalvikvm(19250): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41093930)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09009f type #0x12 is not valid
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1130)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1217)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1231)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-02 03:35:11.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19250):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gen_assets"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/twoglobe_line"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/genA_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loader_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/info_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/company_name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/company_input"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/info_layout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/project_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/project_name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/project_input"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/generalAssets_load_button_ID"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/load" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't see mysql_queries echo anything back? Test the url in the browser by manually providing the url with company, component, project..

Comment: It doesn't, it's being called through `questions.php` which is the file that's receiving the `POST` and `GET` calls. That file echo's the response. I have tested it in the browser by giving hard coded values. It returns the information I want. Also the first `AsyncTask` returns the values I want. So this is working once, it's just not working when it's being parsed in `LoadAllQuestions`

Comment: I just added an answer, but I think you may have edited with corrections already based on Mohunnad's answer. Good luck!

Comment: what is the line 234 of your code?

Comment: @Muhannad `questionsList.add(map);`

Comment: @i_me_mine I have updated the answer for futrue readings but you must inistialize questionList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
            params);
```

to

```
jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
            params);
```

then **BEFORE** that line, after your ArrayList initialization, add these values to the array, I'm assuming their the same desired values SearchPost uses..

```
        String companyName = cn.getText().toString();
        String projectName = pn.getText().toString();
        String componentName = (String) ab.getSelectedTab().getText();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", companyName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project", projectName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("component", componentName));
```

**EDIT:** 
Initialize the questionList afterwards.

```
 questionList = ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

**EDIT 2:**

Change

```
R.id.genA_layout
```

to

```
R.layout.genA_layout
```

**UPDATE**

You should make a separate xml layout file **defining how each list view row** should look like with two TextViews with ids R.id.answer, R.id.name.

A simple mockup may look like this: (please test, I've coded this straight from the answer box).

**MyListViewRow.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"> <!-- You can make orientation horizontal also -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Afterwards, change R.id.genA_layout to R.layout.MyListViewRow

Comment: @i_me_mine See edit 2, Also, these newly found errors stray away from the initial issue as that has been solved.. I suggest you take some time with any newly found errors and start a new Question if you get stuck again.

Comment: Actually what I would like to inflate is the `ListView`. With the id of android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31063/discussion-between-ryan-and-i-me-mine)

Answer (score 1):

You use a GET request in your Android app, but you try to get POST data in your PHP code. I guess you should change this:

```
jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
            params);
```

To this:

```
jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST",
            params);
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it still gives me the same error. Like I said I think the `POST` in `SearchPost` which gives `mysql_queries` its values is no longer valid by the time it's being parsed in `LoadAllQuestions`

Comment: You create a new `NameValuePair`, but you don't add any values to it. You should add the same values as in `SearchPost` because now it doesn't supply any POST values. Note that you should still change GET to POST.

Answer (score 1):

The second AsyncTask doesn't add any parameter to the request i.e company ,project and component.In addition You are not checking the existence of the params in the request and as mentioned in @koesie answer you must change the request type to POST instead of GET.

Because You are sending GET request so the params should be available in $_GET , but the php code checks for $_POST data.

Hope this would help

**Update**
You must initialize questionList

```
questionList = ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

**UPDATE**

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                        questionsList,
                        R.layout.genA_layout,
                        new String[] { TAG_FIELD, TAG_NAME },
                        new int[] { R.id.answer, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I edited the post again, new logcat after instantiating properly. Now it looks like my `SimpleListAdapter`

Comment: @i_me_mine Please use layout instead of id in when creating simple adapter see my update

Comment: Actually what I would like to inflate is the `ListView`. With the id of android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: mmm!! but as to my info , the parameter should be layout resource not an ID resource